# My laptop gets super hot when charging since an update under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, overheating

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop（Machrevo,with i5-8265U,nvidia MX250). My laptop's OEM system is Windows 10, and previously it would get super hot (maybe 220F，I guess) when charging. The manufacturer admitted it was caused by defects in BIOS and then I get my BIOS ec updated（on Windows). After that it got cooler under Windows (CPU temperature 160-180F when charging).

But Windows 10 didn't meet my needs so I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Until a week ago, on temperature side, it looked great. Very few times my CPU got hotter than 70F, even charging. But this week after a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` the cooling system seems to have stopped working (the fan does not turn on automatically, and before it had three gears but now it seems **only to work at the minimum** even when the temperature gets higher than 240F (burns my hand) and everything crashes because CPU cannot work in this situation.

I tried installing `tlp` after that. (I just `sudo start tlp`. Will it work?) The temperature went down a bit but is still much higher than before (and expected). I went to `/var/crash` and `/var/log**` but find nothing. So there are no logs I can show you guys.

Here is the output of  `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Device 1b50:1018
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device 1b50:5515
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Maybe someone can help me figure it out? Or tell me how to configure TLP to reduce the heat?

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS? The problem is that the nvidia driver doesn't seem to be properly installed.

Comment: I disabled secure boot in BIOS.I use "intel UHD only" config in nvidia X Server settings in order to reduce power consume

Comment: update:I uninstalled nvidia dirver use _--purge_ option and auto installed driver as ubuntu suggested using 'autoinstall' .After that ,I installed TLP and powertop,made them auto startup on boot.<br>but something wired showed:when I use 'sudo powertop' ,it showd devices that my laptop doesn't have,and after I turned them to "good",the next time they go "bad"<br>'image1':https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/06/05/trn5yq.png   'image2' :https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/06/05/trnx61.png

Comment: update2:today I used my laptop for whole day(with ubuntu for 8h and windwos for 4h) I noticed something

Comment: First ,after those struggle,my laptop get a acceptable temperature when on ubuntu.40C when on battery and 50C plugged(around the cpu) Second,the overheating problem seems still exist in windows.90C suddenly ,and cpu usage was 5%.it was GPU usage blow up for nonsense.Seems like the sensor(BIOS related) still have bugs.Oh Their technical support didn't help all

Answer (score -1):

Under volting helps a lot when there is over heating (and by lot I mean A LOT). To be on a safer side, manufacturers supply higher voltage than required to the CPU (which causes heating), as at very lower voltages CPU doesn't work properly under stress. Under volting is completely safe. It will not void your warranty what so ever. Under volting is basically removing the excess voltage supplied and giving the minimum voltage required to run the CPU smoothly.

Try `intel-undervolt` from [here](https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt).

[Here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1932) is a guide to help you along.

Some terms in the guide might be depricated. Refer the first link for the deprecated terms.

As of selecting the offset, I use `undervolt 0 'CPU' -130` in the `/etc/intel-undervolt.conf` file. As a beginner I would suggest you to stick to undervolting the CPU only.

To find the correct offset (unique to each CPU piece. Same CPU but on different computer could have different ideal offset) slowly  lower the offset by small values (I used 10), and at the point where your PC crashes, is the threshold. And set the final value to threshold - 10. In my case it crashed at 140 so I set is to 130.

The only down side is that you will have to apply the settings on every boot. I have created an alias with `alias us='sudo intel-undervolt apply && sudo tlp start'`. So I just have to type `us` in the terminal on a boot, and then I am good to go.

**Note:** the crashing of PC to calculate the offset is completely safe. It will not damage you hardware whatsoever.

**Note:** Any Intel CPU can go to -125 at least, above that comes the difficult part. If you want to take it to the limit, then only try increasing it step by step. Other wise -125 will work just fine for any Intel CPU.

Comment: The problem seems caused by an update (a driver problem) in this case, so rather than posting a generic solution again, it may be preferable to link to [the answer you already posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247969/lenovo-y540-overheating-issue/1260064#1260064) in a comment on the question. While it may be the case that the same answer is applicable to multiple questions, and very occasionally posting the same answer again *might* be OK, more often the same answer applying is a sign that the questions are duplicates, or that the details of the question point to a non-generic answer.

Comment: @Zanna Duly noted. Thank you for pointing that out. I will do so in the future.